# How to format ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, code-formatting

I would like to format ruby source code using a command line application, so that it is beautified as per ruby guidelines. Is there any such application?

Comment: I don't think that can be automated. Even when following some standard, you cannot format a code without knowing the intention of each part or the code. A text editor or an IDE can assist that, but it cannot be done without manual decision made my human.

Comment: It doesn't matter, I would like to format this code and see how it turns out

Comment: Not tried it, but: http://www.arachnoid.com/ruby/rubyBeautifier.html based on searching "Perl::Tidy for Ruby"

Comment: @sawa: Perl has Perl::Tidy, and it's reasonable

Comment: @NeilSlater For example, if you have a chain `foo.bar.baz....` that goes long and cannot fit a normal single line. How does the program know where is should be line-broken?

Comment: @sawa: A code tidier need not cope with all cases, it just needs to output code that is semantically identical, and at least as tidy as its input. Perl::Tidy copes well with indentation and whitespace management for this reason - whitespace has no semantic meaning in Perl, so it can be adjusted with relative ease.

Comment: @NeilSlater ruby beautifier doesn't work, I already tried it

Comment: I am primarily looking at correcting indentation and spaces

Answer (score 1):

you can also use VIM for this:

```
vim source.rb +'norm gg=G' +x
```

it will only fix the indentation, though.